# C# WCF Proxy Deserialization - Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'run'

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services, soap

I'm attempting to consume a SOAP Web Service through WCF using .NET Core 5.

I believe the soap response from the webservice has some legacy xml that can't be deserialized.
Do you see anything particularly wrong with the xml? Is there a way I can override this behavior?

Here is the Error Message: "Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'run'."

The Xml Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wss="http://www.adonix.com/WSS">
  <s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
  <soapenv:Body>
    <wss:runResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <runReturn xsi:type="wss:CAdxResultXml">
        <messages xsi:type="soapenc:Array" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" soapenc:arrayType="wss:CAdxMessage[0]"></messages>
        <resultXml xsi:type="xsd:string"><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><RESULT><GRP ID="GRP1"><FLD NAME="ITMREF" TYPE="Char">100001</FLD></GRP><TAB DIM="10" ID="GRP2" SIZE="10"><LIN NUM="1"><FLD NAME="UNSPSC" TYPE="Char">30251503</FLD><FLD NAME="SUPPLIERAID" TYPE="Char">100007</FLD><FLD NAME="QTYMIN" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="QTYINTERVAL" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="PRIQTY" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="PRIAMT2" TYPE="Char">174.37</FLD><FLD NAME="PRIAMT1" TYPE="Char">195.85</FLD><FLD NAME="ORDERUNIT" TYPE="Char">PK</FLD><FLD NAME="MIMEINFO" TYPE="Char">https://www.packbgr.com/images/gluesticks-670.jpg</FLD><FLD NAME="MFGNAME" TYPE="Char">BGR</FLD><FLD NAME="MFGAID" TYPE="Char">00-051111-91711-4</FLD><FLD NAME="LOWERBOUND2" TYPE="Char">11</FLD><FLD NAME="LOWERBOUND1" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="DLVTIME" TYPE="Char">9</FLD><FLD NAME="DESCSHORT" TYPE="Char">3750AE TAN JET-MELT G.P. HOT MELT ADHESIVE 25#/CS 1/2&quot;X10&quot; </FLD><FLD NAME="DESCLONG" TYPE="Char">3750AE TAN JET-MELT G.P. HOT MELT ADHESIVE 25#/CS 1/2&quot;X10&quot; </FLD><FLD NAME="CURRENCY" TYPE="Char">USD</FLD><FLD NAME="CATEGORY2" TYPE="Char">Hot Melt Glue Sticks</FLD><FLD NAME="CATEGORY1" TYPE="Char">Glue and Adhesives</FLD><FLD NAME="CONTENTUNIT" TYPE="Char">LB</FLD><FLD NAME="CONTENTCOEFF" TYPE="Char">25.00</FLD></LIN><LIN NUM="2"><FLD NAME="UNSPSC" TYPE="Char">30251503</FLD><FLD NAME="SUPPLIERAID" TYPE="Char">100008</FLD><FLD NAME="QTYMIN" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="QTYINTERVAL" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="PRIQTY" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="PRIAMT2" TYPE="Char">141.32</FLD><FLD NAME="PRIAMT1" TYPE="Char">158.72</FLD><FLD NAME="ORDERUNIT" TYPE="Char">PK</FLD><FLD NAME="MIMEINFO" TYPE="Char"/><FLD NAME="MFGNAME" TYPE="Char">BGR</FLD><FLD NAME="MFGAID" TYPE="Char">00-051115-25579-3</FLD><FLD NAME="LOWERBOUND2" TYPE="Char">11</FLD><FLD NAME="LOWERBOUND1" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="DLVTIME" TYPE="Char">9</FLD><FLD NAME="DESCSHORT" TYPE="Char">3762 LM AE JET-MELT ADHESIVE .45&quot;DIA.X12&quot;LG. 11#/BOX </FLD><FLD NAME="DESCLONG" TYPE="Char">3762 LM AE JET-MELT ADHESIVE .45&quot;DIA.X12&quot;LG. 11#/BOX </FLD><FLD NAME="CURRENCY" TYPE="Char">USD</FLD><FLD NAME="CATEGORY2" TYPE="Char">Hot Melt Glue Sticks</FLD><FLD NAME="CATEGORY1" TYPE="Char">Glue and Adhesives</FLD><FLD NAME="CONTENTUNIT" TYPE="Char">LB</FLD><FLD NAME="CONTENTCOEFF" TYPE="Char">11.00</FLD></LIN><LIN NUM="3"><FLD NAME="UNSPSC" TYPE="Char">30251503</FLD><FLD NAME="SUPPLIERAID" TYPE="Char">100009</FLD><FLD NAME="QTYMIN" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="QTYINTERVAL" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="PRIQTY" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="PRIAMT2" TYPE="Char">272.33</FLD><FLD NAME="PRIAMT1" TYPE="Char">305.88</FLD><FLD NAME="ORDERUNIT" TYPE="Char">PK</FLD><FLD NAME="MIMEINFO" TYPE="Char">https://www.packbgr.com/images/100009-670.jpg</FLD><FLD NAME="MFGNAME" TYPE="Char">BGR</FLD><FLD NAME="MFGAID" TYPE="Char">00-021200-49128-3</FLD><FLD NAME="LOWERBOUND2" TYPE="Char">10</FLD><FLD NAME="LOWERBOUND1" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="DLVTIME" TYPE="Char">9</FLD><FLD NAME="DESCSHORT" TYPE="Char">3762 LM JET-MELT ADHESIVE PG 1&quot;DIA.X3&quot;LG. 22#/BOX </FLD><FLD NAME="DESCLONG" TYPE="Char">3762 LM JET-MELT ADHESIVE PG 1&quot;DIA.X3&quot;LG. 22#/BOX </FLD><FLD NAME="CURRENCY" TYPE="Char">USD</FLD><FLD NAME="CATEGORY2" TYPE="Char">Hot Melt Glue Sticks</FLD><FLD NAME="CATEGORY1" TYPE="Char">Glue and Adhesives</FLD><FLD NAME="CONTENTUNIT" TYPE="Char">LB</FLD><FLD NAME="CONTENTCOEFF" TYPE="Char">22.00</FLD></LIN><LIN NUM="4"><FLD NAME="UNSPSC" TYPE="Char">30251503</FLD><FLD NAME="SUPPLIERAID" TYPE="Char">100010</FLD><FLD NAME="QTYMIN" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="QTYINTERVAL" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="PRIQTY" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="PRIAMT2" TYPE="Char">179.81</FLD><FLD NAME="PRIAMT1" TYPE="Char">201.96</FLD><FLD NAME="ORDERUNIT" TYPE="Char">PK</FLD><FLD NAME="MIMEINFO" TYPE="Char">https://www.packbgr.com/images/gluesticks-670.jpg</FLD><FLD NAME="MFGNAME" TYPE="Char">BGR</FLD><FLD NAME="MFGAID" TYPE="Char">00-021200-49125-2</FLD><FLD NAME="LOWERBOUND2" TYPE="Char">10</FLD><FLD NAME="LOWERBOUND1" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="DLVTIME" TYPE="Char">9</FLD><FLD NAME="DESCSHORT" TYPE="Char">3762 LM JET-MELT ADHESIVE Q 5/8&quot;DIA.X8&quot;LG. 11#/BOX </FLD><FLD NAME="DESCLONG" TYPE="Char">3762 LM JET-MELT ADHESIVE Q 5/8&quot;DIA.X8&quot;LG. 11#/BOX </FLD><FLD NAME="CURRENCY" TYPE="Char">USD</FLD><FLD NAME="CATEGORY2" TYPE="Char">Hot Melt Glue Sticks</FLD><FLD NAME="CATEGORY1" TYPE="Char">Glue and Adhesives</FLD><FLD NAME="CONTENTUNIT" TYPE="Char">LB</FLD><FLD NAME="CONTENTCOEFF" TYPE="Char">11.00</FLD></LIN><LIN NUM="5"><FLD NAME="UNSPSC" TYPE="Char">30251503</FLD><FLD NAME="SUPPLIERAID" TYPE="Char">100011</FLD><FLD NAME="QTYMIN" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="QTYINTERVAL" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="PRIQTY" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="PRIAMT2" TYPE="Char">169.55</FLD><FLD NAME="PRIAMT1" TYPE="Char">190.43</FLD><FLD NAME="ORDERUNIT" TYPE="Char">PK</FLD><FLD NAME="MIMEINFO" TYPE="Char"/><FLD NAME="MFGNAME" TYPE="Char">BGR</FLD><FLD NAME="MFGAID" TYPE="Char">00-021200-82583-5</FLD><FLD NAME="LOWERBOUND2" TYPE="Char">11</FLD><FLD NAME="LOWERBOUND1" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="DLVTIME" TYPE="Char">9</FLD><FLD NAME="DESCSHORT" TYPE="Char">3792 AE CLEAR HOT MELT ADHES. .45&quot;X12&quot; 11#/CASE </FLD><FLD NAME="DESCLONG" TYPE="Char">3792 AE CLEAR HOT MELT ADHES. .45&quot;X12&quot; 11#/CASE </FLD><FLD NAME="CURRENCY" TYPE="Char">USD</FLD><FLD NAME="CATEGORY2" TYPE="Char">Hot Melt Glue Sticks</FLD><FLD NAME="CATEGORY1" TYPE="Char">Glue and Adhesives</FLD><FLD NAME="CONTENTUNIT" TYPE="Char">LB</FLD><FLD NAME="CONTENTCOEFF" TYPE="Char">11.00</FLD></LIN><LIN NUM="6"><FLD NAME="UNSPSC" TYPE="Char">30251503</FLD><FLD NAME="SUPPLIERAID" TYPE="Char">100012</FLD><FLD NAME="QTYMIN" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="QTYINTERVAL" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="PRIQTY" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="PRIAMT2" TYPE="Char">183.48</FLD><FLD NAME="PRIAMT1" TYPE="Char">206.08</FLD><FLD NAME="ORDERUNIT" TYPE="Char">PK</FLD><FLD NAME="MIMEINFO" TYPE="Char"/><FLD NAME="MFGNAME" TYPE="Char">BGR</FLD><FLD NAME="MFGAID" TYPE="Char">00-021200-82454-8</FLD><FLD NAME="LOWERBOUND2" TYPE="Char">11</FLD><FLD NAME="LOWERBOUND1" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="DLVTIME" TYPE="Char">9</FLD><FLD NAME="DESCSHORT" TYPE="Char">3792 LM JET-MELT ADHESIVE Q 5/8&quot;DIA.X8&quot;LG 11#/BOX </FLD><FLD NAME="DESCLONG" TYPE="Char">3792 LM JET-MELT ADHESIVE Q 5/8&quot;DIA.X8&quot;LG 11#/BOX </FLD><FLD NAME="CURRENCY" TYPE="Char">USD</FLD><FLD NAME="CATEGORY2" TYPE="Char">Hot Melt Glue Sticks</FLD><FLD NAME="CATEGORY1" TYPE="Char">Glue and Adhesives</FLD><FLD NAME="CONTENTUNIT" TYPE="Char">LB</FLD><FLD NAME="CONTENTCOEFF" TYPE="Char">11.00</FLD></LIN><LIN NUM="7"><FLD NAME="UNSPSC" TYPE="Char">30251503</FLD><FLD NAME="SUPPLIERAID" TYPE="Char">100013</FLD><FLD NAME="QTYMIN" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="QTYINTERVAL" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="PRIQTY" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="PRIAMT2" TYPE="Char">230.05</FLD><FLD NAME="PRIAMT1" TYPE="Char">258.39</FLD><FLD NAME="ORDERUNIT" TYPE="Char">PK</FLD><FLD NAME="MIMEINFO" TYPE="Char">https://www.packbgr.com/images/gluesticks-670.jpg</FLD><FLD NAME="MFGNAME" TYPE="Char">BGR</FLD><FLD NAME="MFGAID" TYPE="Char">00-021200-65263-9</FLD><FLD NAME="LOWERBOUND2" TYPE="Char">10</FLD><FLD NAME="LOWERBOUND1" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="DLVTIME" TYPE="Char">9</FLD><FLD NAME="DESCSHORT" TYPE="Char">3792Q JET-MELT ADHESIVE 5/8&quot;DIA.X8&quot;LG. 11#/BOX </FLD><FLD NAME="DESCLONG" TYPE="Char">3792Q JET-MELT ADHESIVE 5/8&quot;DIA.X8&quot;LG. 11#/BOX </FLD><FLD NAME="CURRENCY" TYPE="Char">USD</FLD><FLD NAME="CATEGORY2" TYPE="Char">Hot Melt Glue Sticks</FLD><FLD NAME="CATEGORY1" TYPE="Char">Glue and Adhesives</FLD><FLD NAME="CONTENTUNIT" TYPE="Char">LB</FLD><FLD NAME="CONTENTCOEFF" TYPE="Char">11.00</FLD></LIN><LIN NUM="8"><FLD NAME="UNSPSC" TYPE="Char">30251503</FLD><FLD NAME="SUPPLIERAID" TYPE="Char">100018</FLD><FLD NAME="QTYMIN" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="QTYINTERVAL" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="PRIQTY" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="PRIAMT2" TYPE="Char">129.54</FLD><FLD NAME="PRIAMT1" TYPE="Char">145.50</FLD><FLD NAME="ORDERUNIT" TYPE="Char">PK</FLD><FLD NAME="MIMEINFO" TYPE="Char">https://www.packbgr.com/images/hotmeltgluechips-670.jpg</FLD><FLD NAME="MFGNAME" TYPE="Char">BGR</FLD><FLD NAME="MFGAID" TYPE="Char">07470-000-AZ</FLD><FLD NAME="LOWERBOUND2" TYPE="Char">10</FLD><FLD NAME="LOWERBOUND1" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="DLVTIME" TYPE="Char">6</FLD><FLD NAME="DESCSHORT" TYPE="Char">#7470 HIGH TEMP HOT MELT GLUE 50#/CS 36CS/PALLET </FLD><FLD NAME="DESCLONG" TYPE="Char">#7470 HIGH TEMP HOT MELT GLUE 50#/CS 36CS/PALLET </FLD><FLD NAME="CURRENCY" TYPE="Char">USD</FLD><FLD NAME="CATEGORY2" TYPE="Char">Hot Melt Glue Chips</FLD><FLD NAME="CATEGORY1" TYPE="Char">Glue and Adhesives</FLD><FLD NAME="CONTENTUNIT" TYPE="Char">LB</FLD><FLD NAME="CONTENTCOEFF" TYPE="Char">50.00</FLD></LIN><LIN NUM="9"><FLD NAME="UNSPSC" TYPE="Char">30251503</FLD><FLD NAME="SUPPLIERAID" TYPE="Char">100021</FLD><FLD NAME="QTYMIN" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="QTYINTERVAL" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="PRIQTY" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="PRIAMT2" TYPE="Char">181.63</FLD><FLD NAME="PRIAMT1" TYPE="Char">204.00</FLD><FLD NAME="ORDERUNIT" TYPE="Char">PK</FLD><FLD NAME="MIMEINFO" TYPE="Char">https://www.packbgr.com/images/hotmeltgluechips-670.jpg</FLD><FLD NAME="MFGNAME" TYPE="Char">BGR</FLD><FLD NAME="MFGAID" TYPE="Char">7250</FLD><FLD NAME="LOWERBOUND2" TYPE="Char">10</FLD><FLD NAME="LOWERBOUND1" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="DLVTIME" TYPE="Char">6</FLD><FLD NAME="DESCSHORT" TYPE="Char">#7250 HOT MELT GLUE CHIPS 50LB/BG </FLD><FLD NAME="DESCLONG" TYPE="Char">#7250 HOT MELT GLUE CHIPS 50LB/BG </FLD><FLD NAME="CURRENCY" TYPE="Char">USD</FLD><FLD NAME="CATEGORY2" TYPE="Char">Hot Melt Glue Chips</FLD><FLD NAME="CATEGORY1" TYPE="Char">Glue and Adhesives</FLD><FLD NAME="CONTENTUNIT" TYPE="Char">LB</FLD><FLD NAME="CONTENTCOEFF" TYPE="Char">50.00</FLD></LIN><LIN NUM="10"><FLD NAME="UNSPSC" TYPE="Char">30251503</FLD><FLD NAME="SUPPLIERAID" TYPE="Char">100027</FLD><FLD NAME="QTYMIN" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="QTYINTERVAL" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="PRIQTY" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="PRIAMT2" TYPE="Char">82.93</FLD><FLD NAME="PRIAMT1" TYPE="Char">93.15</FLD><FLD NAME="ORDERUNIT" TYPE="Char">PK</FLD><FLD NAME="MIMEINFO" TYPE="Char">https://www.packbgr.com/images/hotmeltgluechips-670.jpg</FLD><FLD NAME="MFGNAME" TYPE="Char">BGR</FLD><FLD NAME="MFGAID" TYPE="Char">100027</FLD><FLD NAME="LOWERBOUND2" TYPE="Char">10</FLD><FLD NAME="LOWERBOUND1" TYPE="Char">1</FLD><FLD NAME="DLVTIME" TYPE="Char">6</FLD><FLD NAME="DESCSHORT" TYPE="Char">505/PW PILLOWS PSA GLUE 25LB/CS </FLD><FLD NAME="DESCLONG" TYPE="Char">505/PW PILLOWS PSA GLUE 25LB/CS </FLD><FLD NAME="CURRENCY" TYPE="Char">USD</FLD><FLD NAME="CATEGORY2" TYPE="Char">Hot Melt Glue Chips</FLD><FLD NAME="CATEGORY1" TYPE="Char">Glue and Adhesives</FLD><FLD NAME="CONTENTUNIT" TYPE="Char">LB</FLD><FLD NAME="CONTENTCOEFF" TYPE="Char">25.00</FLD></LIN></TAB></RESULT>]]></resultXml>
        <status xsi:type="xsd:int">1</status>
        <technicalInfos xsi:type="wss:CAdxTechnicalInfos">
          <busy xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</busy>
          <changeLanguage xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</changeLanguage>
          <changeUserId xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</changeUserId>
          <flushAdx xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</flushAdx>
          <loadWebsDuration xsi:type="xsd:double">0</loadWebsDuration>
          <nbDistributionCycle xsi:type="xsd:int">-1</nbDistributionCycle>
          <poolDistribDuration xsi:type="xsd:double">0</poolDistribDuration>
          <poolEntryIdx xsi:type="xsd:int">16028</poolEntryIdx>
          <poolExecDuration xsi:type="xsd:double">2144</poolExecDuration>
          <poolRequestDuration xsi:type="xsd:double">-1</poolRequestDuration>
          <poolWaitDuration xsi:type="xsd:double">0</poolWaitDuration>
          <processReport xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true" />
          <processReportSize xsi:type="xsd:int">-1</processReportSize>
          <reloadWebs xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</reloadWebs>
          <resumitAfterDBOpen xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</resumitAfterDBOpen>
          <rowInDistribStack xsi:type="xsd:int" xsi:nil="true" />
          <totalDuration xsi:type="xsd:double">2161</totalDuration>
          <traceRequest xsi:type="xsd:string" />
          <traceRequestSize xsi:type="xsd:int">0</traceRequestSize>
        </technicalInfos>
      </runReturn>
    </wss:runResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My Code: https://github.com/abiddle-bgr/Test/blob/main/CAdxWebServiceXmlCCClient.cs

Here is the inner exception:
[image]
Stack Trace:
[image]

Comment: Exception says you  are trying to deserialize a dictionary.  See following : https://theburningmonk.com/2010/05/net-tips-xml-serialize-or-deserialize-dictionary-in-csharp/?force_isolation=true